# Delete last / one specific row with what arguments?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to delete the last row of an Excel spreadsheet, but I don't know the format of the argument to put into the rows.delete command. It keeps giving me an error.

```
LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
Rows("LastRow").Delete 'error type mismatch
```

Any suggestions to the argument for rows.delete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Select
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: You can (and should) avoid the Select and Selection and just combine the two lines.

Comment: Yes, I agree your way is better. But I don't enough reputation to vote it up lol

Comment: actually, your method is just fine and a great alternative (and probably how I would have done it).  I just think you can do yours better with the one-line option.  I'll throw you an upvote to help you on the way.

Comment: Also, try using rows.count to allow for different versions of excel.                              
Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).EntireRow.Delete  Or 
Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).EntireRow.Delete

Answer (score 3):

```
LastRow.EntireRow.Delete  Shift:=xlShiftUp
```